# What should I watch/read before watching all the three Transformers movies?

Tags: suggested-order, transformers

I know a very little about the Transformers. I'm planning to watch all the three movies. Do I need to watch anything else or are the movies sufficient to explain everything?

Comment: Just watch all of them in their respective sequence. No need to watch/read anything before tha...everything in the movieis self-explainatory

Comment: Everything in the movies is *non*-explanatory, you mean.

Comment: @JohnO The explanation for everything in those movies is *Michael Bay*.  As in, why are there so many explosions?  *Michael Bay*.

Comment: I first encountered `Transformers` on Cartoon Network India before the launch of the three movies. I loved its story by heart. And, believe me.. this love made me to dislike the movies. The movie was fully in different universe with poor story.

Comment: Read the [Roger](http://rogerebert.suntimes.com/apps/pbcs.dll/article?AID=%2F20070705%2FREVIEWS%2F70620006%2F1023&AID1=%2F20070705%2FREVIEWS%2F70620006%2F1023&AID2=) [Ebert](http://rogerebert.suntimes.com/apps/pbcs.dll/article?AID=/20110628/REVIEWS/110629981) [reviews](http://rogerebert.suntimes.com/apps/pbcs.dll/article?AID=/20090623/REVIEWS/906239997). Then watch something better instead.

Comment: So we're in agreement then, Michael Bay, or rather explosions, don't really need explanations. These are just movies with candy for the eyes...

Comment: @Beta You know he gave the *first* movie 3/4 stars and a pretty good review, right? (The other two, of course, were abominations that should be dropped into the pit with Highlander II.)

Comment: There are a few scenes and quotes in "Transformers" that are intended as nods to the first three 1984 G1 episodes or the 1985 animated movie. Not necessary viewing, but it's fun to spot them.

Comment: First watch every other movie ever made. The *maybe* check out Transformers if you’re really, really bored.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As with most of sci-fi movie series, there's nothing in Transformers movies which needs explanation from external sources. So, even if you are not familiar with Transformers universe, you can watch movies directly in release order.

If want to dive deep in Transformers movies' story continuity, I'd recommend you to go for related comic series. Here's viewing/reading order:

1. Transformers: Saga of the Allspark (Comic Series)
2. Transformers: Movie Prequel (Comic Series)
3. **Transformers** (Movie)
4. Transformers: Movie Adaptation (Comic Series)
5. Transformers: The Reign of Starscream (Comic Series)
6. Transformers: Alliance (Comic Series; Story Arc is a part of "Transformers: Destiny")
7. Transformers: Defiance (Comic Series; Story Arc is a part of "Transformers: Destiny")
8. **Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen** (Movie)
9. Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen Movie Adaptation (Comic Series)
10. Transformers: Nefarious (Comic Series)
11. Transformers: Sector 7 (Comic Series)
12. Transformers: Foundation (Comic Series)
13. Transformers: Rising Storm (Comic Series)
14. **Transformers: Dark of the Moon** (Movie)
15. Transformers: Dark of the Moon Movie Adaptation (Comic Series)

Answer (score 7):

**The films are in their own standalone continuity and no prior knowledge is required.**

There are a number of [comic book tie-ins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers_%28film_comic_series%29) to the movie, but none are essential reading.

For each film there were a number of novels released:

- [Transformers](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Movie_%28books%29)
- [Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Revenge_of_the_Fallen_%28books%29)
- [Transformers: Dark of the Moon](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Dark_of_the_Moon_%28books%29)

Answer (score 6):

As everyone has already stated, there is no prerequisite for watching/enjoying [Michael Bay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Bay)'s Transformers films. The origins of [Transformers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers) is that it's a toy line that grew into other things such as comics, cartoons, movies, and various other products.

If you grew up during the 1980s as a kid in the United States, you should not only be familiar with the toys, but also the animated movie, [Transformers: The Movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092106/) that came out in 1986. The Michael Bay movies draws not only a voice actor from the orignal cartoon and movie, but some famous dialog that Transformers fans should be familiar with.

[image: Transformers: The Movie]

Again, by no means is this movie necessary viewing.

If you grew up during that era, you would already want to revisit the childhood movie.

If not, then I urge you to go into Bay's movies with an open mind, so that you have nothing to compare them against. That way you can't critique what they got right, what was wrong. You can enjoy the movies for what they are.

Comment: You can watch the whole thing here :) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJ9jEMs50CY  Full movie on youtube!

Comment: "by no means is this movie necessary viewing" - as long as you ignore the fact that it's The Greatest Motion Picture Ever Made.